# What is the difference between Rake and Ansible?

Tags: ruby, ansible, rake

I have been learning some new technologies for automatization of workflow. On some projects I saw people using Rakefiles. I have learned that they are used to automate the deployment/workflow etc.
On others, I saw people using Ansible.
Maybe I am misunderstanding one of those technologies, but how do they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rake is a tool most often used for administrative tasks that can be scripted for an application whether that be database migrations, data loading, export/import of data, clearing caches, etc.  Ansible is a provisioning tool it can configure a server, and do application deployment.  You could conceivably use rake to do some of what Ansible does and vice versa, but if you were to try to recreate Ansible in a rake utility you'd be re-inventing the wheel.  The closer equivalent to Anisble in the ruby/rails world is [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/).  However, Ansible is a more generically applicable tool and Capistrano is more a specialty tool for rails applications (IMO).

Comment: You might launch a Rake task from Ansible, but it'd be very odd to do the opposite.